# Validation for Dropdowns in angular, If slected value is yes from 2nd Dropdown then validation should be mandatory for 3rd dropdown

Tags: angular, validation

I am doing validation for Dropdowns. I have three dropdowns.
1) 1st and 2nd dropdowns are Mandatory but for 3rd dropdown, I need to write a logic for it
   and the logic is for 2nd dropdown if the value is "yes" then 3rd dropdown should mark as mandatory otherwise not needed.
2) I have Reset  button and it should reset the values.
I have tried but unable to find the soultion.
 Please can anyone help me in this?? Thanks in Advance..

```
export class AppComponent  {
  PepPartner : "";
  PepBlacklisted : "";
  Blacklist : "";
  public formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

   screenofAML() {
    let self = this;
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({

       PepPartner :['',Validators.required],
      PepBlacklisted :['',Validators.required],
      Blacklist :['',Validators.required],

    });
  }


  validateForm() {
    if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
      this.formGroup.get('PepPartner').markAsTouched();
      this.formGroup.get('PepBlacklisted').markAsTouched();
      this.formGroup.get('Blacklist').markAsTouched();
           return;
    }
    else {
      const dataObj = {
       PepPartner:this.formGroup.get('PepPartner').value,
        PepBlacklisted:this.formGroup.get('PepBlacklisted').value,
        Blacklist :this.formGroup.get('Blacklist').value,

      }

    }

}

 onResetClick() {
    this.PepPartner = "";
   this. PepBlacklisted = "";
   this.Blacklist ="";
  }

}



<div class ="space">
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>Is this partner a PEP?</mat-label>
     <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('PepPartner').hasError('required')">
        PEP Partner  is required
      </mat-error>
  <mat-select disableRipple  [(ngModel)]="PepPartner" formControlName="PepPartner">
      <mat-option ></mat-option>
    <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Does this partner blacklisted</mat-label>
  <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('PepBlacklisted').hasError('required')">
      Partner blacklisted is required
    </mat-error>
  <mat-select disableRipple  [(ngModel)]="PepBlacklisted" formControlName="PepBlacklisted" >
    <mat-option ></mat-option>
    <mat-option value="1">Yes</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="2">No</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field >
       <mat-error *ngIf="formGroup.get('Blacklist').hasError('required')">
      Blacklisted is required
      </mat-error>

    <input matInput  placeholder="Blacklist(s)"  [(ngModel)]="Blacklist" formControlName="Blacklist" >

  </mat-form-field>

  <div class="button-position">
      <div class="text-right pr-0 pb-2">
        <div class="btn-group">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button type="button" id="button1" mat-raised-button class="text-uppercase app-btn app-btn-

  primary-border app-color-primary"
         (click)="validateForm()" >Save</button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button type="button" id="button2" mat-raised-button class="text-uppercase app-btn app-btn-

  primary-border app-color-primary"
            (click)="onResetClick()">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is not very clear if the value is "yes" yet in your stackbliz you have names of people and values of [i] which are numeric.  One easy option is to make the 3rd drop down invisible using *ngIf and adding the required tag.

Comment: @ Farasi.. Thanks for your response.. I have edited my code now. So can you tell me the solutions how can do that..Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you stackbliz this please?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a flag like selectRequired and set it false in your select-form-example.ts

```
selectRequired = false;
```

After in changeClient2 function

```
changeClient2(data){
alert("selected --->"+this.clients[data].id+' '+this.clients[data].clientName);
  // here you can check that it's value yes/no
  this.clients[data].id === 'id2' ? this.selectRequired = true : this.selectRequired = false;
}
```

At last add 3rd select and **[required]='selectRequired'** in your select-form-example.html

It depends on selectRequired is true or false

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Clients" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue3" name="food" (change)="changeClient2($event.value)" [required]='selectRequired'>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index;" [value]="i">
    {{client.clientName}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: @ Beller .. Thanks for your response.. I have edited code now. So can you tell me the solutions how can do that..Thanks in Advance